# Mysql and flyway command line afterMigrate.sql with multiple files

Tags: mysql, flyway

Im using a MySQL database and playing around with flyway command line tool (http://flywaydb.org/).  Ideally I'd like to see separation between the schema migration changes and stored procs/functions i.e.

```
src/db/V01__init.sql
src/db/procs/01_util.sql
src/db/procs/02_time.sql
...
```

Ive found the afterMigrate.sql file which gets triggered at the completion of  the migrate command from the command line.  But cannot see how I would include all the 2 stored proc files I have.

I tried putting this into the afterMigrate.sql

```
SOURCE 'procs/01_util.sql';
SOURCE 'procs/02_time.sql';
```

However seems to result in an SQL Syntax error.

Is there some way i can include the stored proc files inside the afterMigrate file short of defining it all inside one file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no, with 3.X you have to put them into one file or implement your own call back in Java.

For 4.0, we will indroduce first class support for these types of repeatable scripts that should make this much easier.

Comment: Ok, look forward to 4.0.  For now I crudely modified the flyway script file to appending the contents of all the files under the proc folder to the afterMigrate.sql file using 
cat procs/*.sql > afterMigrate.sql

Works ok for now